# Foto tirada pela câmara retorna invertida

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Existe alguma forma de não inverter a foto após atualizar ela numa ImageView?
Por exemplo, o aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo acessa a câmera do dispositivo e depois de tirar a foto, atualiza o ImageView com a foto invertida. Queria deixar ela da mesma forma que é visualizada na biblioteca de fotos do celular.

No meu código, já estou conseguindo alterar o tamanho da imagem depois de atualizar no ImageView.

**Código**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
ImageView imageCapturedView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageCapturedView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageCapturedView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            abrirCamera();
        }

    });
}

public void abrirCamera(){
    Intent captureImageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(captureImageIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
        File photoFile=null;

        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch(IOException e){

        }

        if(photoFile != null) {
            captureImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(captureImageIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        //Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        //imageCapturedView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        galleryAddPic();
        setPic();
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String TimeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String ImageFile = "JPEG_" + TimeStamp + "_";
    File StorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(ImageFile, ".jpg", StorageDir);

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;

}

private void galleryAddPic()
{
    /*Intent mediaScan = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f= new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScan.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScan);*/
}

private void setPic() throws ArithmeticException{
    int scaleFactor;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = imageCapturedView.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageCapturedView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    if(targetH == 0) targetH = 1;
    if(targetW == 0) targetW = 1;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    scaleFactor= Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mCurrentPhotoPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    imageCapturedView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

/* ----------------------------------- */

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // adiciona itens para a barra de ação, se ela estiver presente.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: Veja se esta [minha resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20480741/2556111) ajuda

Comment: Ajudou!!!Vou editar minha resposta. @ramaral

Answer (score 3):

Dependendo do drive da câmara do celular este roda a foto antes de gravar ou guarda o valor da rotação no EXIF na TAG_ORIENTATION.

Assim, para que o nosso programa possa apresentar a foto corretamente, temos que ler o EXIF associado à foto e rodá-la de acordo com a TAG_ORIENTATION .

Código para obter a rotação gravada no EXIF:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);  
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

Código para rodar a foto:

```
Bitmap bmRotated = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);
```

Método para rodar o bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

    try{
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
           case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
               matrix.setRotate(90);
               break;
           case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
               matrix.setRotate(-90);
               matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
               break;
           case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
               matrix.setRotate(-90);
               break;
           default:
               return bitmap;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Seu post foi muito útil. Tenho apenas uma dúvida. Aproveitei esse mesmo aplicativo para acessar a biblioteca de fotos do celular, ao invés de abrir a câmera. Após acessar as fotos, eu posso selecionar qualquer foto e atualizar o ImageView que coloquei no meu app. A questão é que eu consigo selecionar a atualizar qualquer foto, exceto as que foram tiradas pela câmera. Desconfio que isso esteja ocorrendo porque a foto está sendo carregada num tamanho maior que o do display. Será que se eu redimensionar a foto via código conseguirei tratar as fotos tiradas pela câmera? @ramaral

Comment: Não entendo o que quer dizer com:*"exceto as que foram tiradas pela câmera"*

Comment: Quando entro na galeria de fotos do meu celular, tenho diversos diretórios contendo imagens, por exemplo, fotos que recebi no whatsapp, fotos do instagram, facebook etc. No diretório que ficam as fotos que eu mesmo tirei do meu celular, quando as escolho, elas não aparecem no meu app. As demais fotos que mencionei aparecem. @ramaral

Comment: Julgo que seria melhor você postar nova pergunta expondo esse problema, inclua o código que está usando.

Comment: Postei novo questionamento com o código em [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47056/redimensionar-imagens-da-c%C3%A2mera-android-app] @ramaral