# Redimensionar Imagens da Câmera

Tags: android, android-camera

Estou trabalhando num aplicativo que acessa a biblioteca de fotos e atualiza uma ImageView com a foto selecionada na biblioteca do celular.
Tenho um LG G2 e minha câmera é configurada por default para tirar fotos com a resolução 4160x2340. Se eu selecionar alguma foto nessa resolução, ela acaba não cabendo na tela do aplicativo. O app não retorna nenhum erro porque ele acaba conseguindo tratar a imagem, porém ela não é exibida em virtude do tamanho. Se eu alterar as configurações para 1280x960, por exemplo, a condição funciona perfeitamente e a foto é carregada com sucesso.

Gostaria de redimendionar a foto deixando num tamanho default independente da configuração ou resolução que a foto foi tirada.

Como sou iniciante no desenvolvimento, se alguém puder me ajudar informando onde devo corrigir ou acrescentar diretamente no meu código, me ajudaria bastante.

**Meu código:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageView img;
private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            abrirFoto();
        }

    });
}

public void abrirFoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    InputStream stream = null;
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null)
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    }
}

private static Bitmap resizeImage(Context context, Bitmap bmpOriginal,
                                  float newWidth, float newHeight) {
    Bitmap novoBmp = null;

    int w = bmpOriginal.getWidth();
    int h = bmpOriginal.getHeight();

    float densityFactor = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float novoW = newWidth * densityFactor;
    float novoH = newHeight * densityFactor;

    //Calcula escala em percentagem do tamanho original para o novo tamanho
    float scalaW = novoW / w;
    float scalaH = novoH / h;

    // Criando uma matrix para manipulação da imagem BitMap
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // Definindo a proporção da escala para o matrix
    matrix.postScale(scalaW, scalaH);

    //criando o novo BitMap com o novo tamanho
    novoBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, w, h, matrix, true);

    return novoBmp;

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não percebo porque é que as imagens maiores não são apresentadas.

Eu utilizo esta função para redimensionar imagens:

```
private static Bitmap resizeImage(Context context, Bitmap bmpOriginal,
                                  float newWidth, float newWeight) {
    Bitmap novoBmp = null;

    int w = bmpOriginal.getWidth();
    int h = bmpOriginal.getHeight();

    float densityFactor = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float novoW = newWidth * densityFactor;
    float novoH = newHeight * densityFactor;

    //Calcula escala em percentagem do tamanho original para o novo tamanho
    float scalaW = novoW / w;
    float scalaH = novoH / h;

    // Criando uma matrix para manipulação da imagem BitMap
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // Definindo a proporção da escala para o matrix
    matrix.postScale(scalaW, scalaH);

    //criando o novo BitMap com o novo tamanho
    novoBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, w, h, matrix, true);

    return novoBmp;
}
```

Você pode utilizá-la assim:

```
img.setImageBitmap(resizeImage(this, bitmap, newWidth, newHeight));
```

Comment: Como eu faço a chamada do comando "img.setImageBitmap(resizeImage(context, image, newWidth, newHeight));" dentro do meu onActivityResult? Editei meu codigo da forma que voce passou, apenas estou me confundindo em como chamar. O código atualizado está aqui na minha própria pergunta. @ramaral

Comment: Substitua a linha `img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` por `img.setImageBitmap(resizeImage(this, bitmap, newWidth, newHeight));` newWidth e newHeight substitua pelos valores que você pretender para a largura e altura da imagem

Comment: Perfeito!!!!@ramaral

Comment: Apenas mais uma coisa, como eu integraria aquele código que você passou para inverter a foto "http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46684/inverter-foto-depois-de-atualizar-no-imageview-do-aplicativo-android" nesse código? Joguei ele nesse código e geraram alguns erros, em "filename" no código "ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);" e na exceção catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
           } @ramaral

Comment: Aqui é necessário um passo mais porque `ExifInterface(filename)` recebe uma string com o path para a imagem. O que você tem é um Uri retornado por `data.getData()`. A solução é converter esse Uri em uma string. Uma função para fazer isso pode ser encontrada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3414749/2556111)