# Como pegar uma imagem da galeria e manter a orientação (retrato/paisagem) no android

Tags: android, imagem, galeria

Tenho um app que pega imagens da galeria do android, mas em alguns dispositivos a orientação da imagem é alterada, gostaria de saber como fazer para manter a orientação original da imagem.

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46707/2541)

Answer (score 1):

Quando é criado um novo projeto, normalmente é gerado um arquivo chamado AndroidManifest.xml, no qual pode configurar a orientação de tela de cada activity criada, entre outras configurações.Basicamente o que é preciso fazer é colocar em cada tag "activity" o código android:screenOrientation="portrait", que ele deixa a tela no modo retrato. Segue um código de exemplo:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Inicio"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```