# Android.Camera2 - Erro de Rotação

Tags: android, qcamera

Boa noite!

Estou tentando implementar a o `android.hardware.camera2` em um projeto, porém estou  com um problema na rotação da câmera!

Acontece o seguinte, antes de tirar a foto, com o celular em PORTRAIT, eu visualizo a foto em pé, normalmente. Porém, acontece que ao virar o celular para LANDSCAPE, em vez da orientação da foto mudar ( eu continuar vendo  ela em pé ) a foto fica de lado, totalmente errado!

Fiz uma imagem para ilustrar o problema.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/014ar.jpg

Não consigo visualizar o motivo disso, e nem encontrar uma solução.

Segue abaixo o código da Activity da câmera e seu holder.

Camera.XML

```
<TextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_takepicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_fab_foto"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="#FFFF56B9"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="#FFD5379B"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_switchcam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_fab_switch"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="#267300"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="#1e5b00"
    fab:fab_size="mini"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
```

Camera.java

```
public class AppCamera extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Size mPreviewSize;

    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;
    private static int cam = 0;

    private FloatingActionButton mBtnShot;
    private FloatingActionButton mBtnSwitch;

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    //Esse trecho serve para rotacionar a imagem depois de tirar a foto, para que a imagem seja salva da forma correta.
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        mTextureView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.texture);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);

        mBtnShot = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_takepicture);
        mBtnSwitch = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_switchcam);

        mBtnShot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }

        });

        mBtnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cam == 0) {
                    cam = 1;
                } else {
                    cam = 0;
                }
                if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                    mCameraDevice.close();
                    mCameraDevice = null;
                }
                openCamera();
            }

        });

    }

    protected void takePicture() {
        if(null == mCameraDevice) {
            return;
        }

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId());

            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics
                        .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                        .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }

            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM", "teste.jpg");

            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream output = null;
                    try {
                        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        output.write(bytes);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != output) {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

            };

            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPicture");
            thread.start();
            final Handler backgroudHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, backgroudHandler);

            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session,
                                               CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {

                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(AppCamera.this, "Saved:"+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startPreview();
                }

            };

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, backgroudHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                }
            }, backgroudHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void openCamera() {

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[cam];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            mPreviewSize = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

            manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener(){

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface,
                                                int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureUpdated");
        }

    };

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {

            mCameraDevice = camera;
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {

        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    }

    protected void startPreview() {

        if(null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }

        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        if(null == texture) {
            return;
        }

        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        try {
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        try {
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    Toast.makeText(AppCamera.this, "onConfigureFailed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void updatePreview() {

        if(null == mCameraDevice) {
        }

        mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
        thread.start();
        Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

        try {
            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46707/2541).

Comment: Obrigado, irei verificar.

Comment: @ramaral, utilizando a classe citada no tópico da resposta, consegui um bom resultado.

A diferença é que ela usa diretamente o "App Camera" do celular, e da forma como eu estava fazendo, criava a própria captura em um layout próprio.