# Upload de foto tirada por celular exibe imagem rotacionada

Tags: android, html, upload, imagem

Tenho um sistema com uma página de Upload de fotos. É um upload de fotos simples, onde se clica no `input`, seleciona a imagem e fim. Depois só enviar o formulário, a imagem é salva em uma pasta, e em outro arquivo html acontece arecuperação do caminho da foto, exibindo a mesma dentro de uma tag `img`.

Se utilizar em um celular ou tablet, o funcionamento é igual, a diferença é que aparece a opção de tirar a foto com a câmera, e logo em seguida ele recupera a imagem exatamente como foi tirada e enviada.

[image: Funcionamento do upload de arquivo em dispositivo Android]

Tudo funciona muito bem, exceto que teve um usuário do sistema, que ao tirar as fotos, o sistema recuperou a imagem deitada, sendo que tirou a foto em pé. Fui salvar a imagem no pc para fazer testes, e a imagem veio do jeito certo. Porém ao fazer o upload dela, ela é exibida novamente deitada. Tudo isso sem fazer nenhuma modificação no arquivo.

[image: Exibição da imagem deitada e imagem em pé]

Qualquer imagem que eu tire foto do meu celular, ou pegue na internet é exibida corretamente. Apenas fotos tiradas pelo Tablet desse usuário são exibidas deitadas. Inclusive se eu tento verificar a foto com o Sublime Text, ele exibe a imagem deitada(rotacionada). Creio que seja algo da configuração da foto, que é definida pelo Android. Pesquisei sobre, mas não encontrei nada especifico.

O que faz a foto ser exibida dessa forma?

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46707/2541)

Answer (score 2):

Se a foto foi criada com algum tipo de câmera digital, provavelmente ela possui *metas* que informam a rotação da câmera no momento do *click*. Você pode utilizar este critério para corrigir a rotação no seu app.

O [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) guarda estas informações no Android.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
// converte para graus
private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {        
  if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { return 90; } 
  else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {  return 180; } 
  else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  return 270; }            
return 0;     
} 
int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
ImageView imageId = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageId) ;
picasso.load("URL").rotate(degrees).into(imageId) ;
```

Boa sorte.

Answer (score -1):

Caso você queria verificar as metas usando PHP a nível de servidor, pode usar a função exif_read_data.

Veja em: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exif-read-data.php

Inclusive tem um exemplo no link falando sobre a orientação da foto.